# How make my Logitech Quickcam e3500 work?

Tags: 11.04, webcam

I have an asus5431 laptop with a built in webcam. This is detected and works fine in Cheese and everyother application. (/dev/video0)

I also have a Quickcam e3500 which is detected by Ubuntu, appears to be loaded as /dev/video1. Only problem is that there is no video. I can use the inbuilt microphone and change the LED status with gstreamerproperties ( i cam make it flash at whatever frequency i like :)) . but no video

I know the camera works since in Mac OS and Windows it is fine.

I do not need the in-built camera since the laptop is under the sofa.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3):

[As you stated in your question:](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/63137/4)

This problem was caused by my USB hub. I tried the camera without the hub and all worked fine. I can still crash the webcam/v4l2 sometimes but a reboot clears that. Annoying but at least I know that the camera works

Answer (score 1):

first thanks to Sergey for the good idea to test our cams, it's simple and works fine!! :D

I have resolved my problem installing the package "v4l2ucp", that give to us an interface to control webcam parameters as brightness, saturation, gain and exposure.

I have modified my parameters and now it works, with both cheese and skype..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is really no video? Can it be that the video is very-very dark? My webcam (Logitec E2500) has a problem with brightness - supposedly there's some problem with its driver and it's auto-changing the brightness to its lowest setting. I found no good solution to this though I don't need my webcam too often.

Try directing some bright light source (a flashlight) directly into the webcam and see if there is something on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be such a common issue when attempting to use the webcam, usb based, for a video conference through a flash player based system, such as Fonomo, Ubiqq, or Skype, etc.

I suggest you to take a look at the answers provided in these questions, which may lead to help you to fix this issue.

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/53495/flash-crashes-on-enabling-webcam/53615#53615
2. [Webcam not detected by Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53028/webcam-not-detected-by-flash/56324#56324)
3. [logitec webcam for notebooks deluxe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57398/logitec-webcam-for-notebooks-deluxe/57539#57539)
4. [QuickCam E 3500 working from Cheese, but not Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23253/quickcam-e-3500-working-from-cheese-but-not-skype/23298#23298)

In my case I fixed that issue by using the Flashcam Project, mentioned on these answers and whose instructions for a correct usage can be reached right here: http://www.swift-tools.net/Flashcam/

Another good trick that makes my days when attempting to use the webcam through web browsers is the usage of Webcam Studio, which can be reached here: http://www.ws4gl.org/. After running the Webcam Studio you will have a virtual "bridge" between your physical webcam and what the Flash Player is expecting to find.

I hope this gives you a clue on where to begin.

Good luck!

Comment: 1. Skype's video is not flash-based; 2. I can't see OP mentioning the webcam doesn't work with Flash only - it looks like there's no video anywhere, including Cheese. The word "flash" in his message refers to "quickly turning on and off", not to the software product :)

Comment: Thank you @Sergey, very illustrative your comment. BTW: I see the question clearly reads "This is detected and works fine in Cheese and everyother application. (/dev/video0)" unless you are talking of a different question. And I yet find my answers useful to find a way for a solution. Unless you drop me another of your interesting "reviews", then I will delete it. Thank you very much for your interest on my errors. Additionally: Feel free to edit it if you think it's needed.

Comment: Re-read this: "...built in webcam ... is detected and works fine in Cheese and every other application", "I also have a Quickcam e3500 which is detected by Ubuntu, [but] there is no video". I agree that your answer may be useful for OP though possibly indirectly.

Comment: How does this lead us to find a solution? Have a nice day @Sergey.