# Using A4Tech camera with Skype

Tags: skype, webcam

I have a A4Tech Pk-635 web cam, and I can view output from web cam in Cheese.
Skype is detecting webcam as `dev/Video0`, but Skype is not generating any output... any ideas?

note:
In case any one else also face this, [here is a solution](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-webcam-problem-in-skype.html) to fix this problem and also update skyp launcher, so that you can launch skype as usual.

Comment: What happens if you run `bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'`???

Comment: may be this link will help you out http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=997807&page=3

Comment: @brunopereira81 yup it started working as expected...

Comment: possible duplicate of [QuickCam E 3500 working from Cheese, but not Skype](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23253/quickcam-e-3500-working-from-cheese-but-not-skype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the skype launcher from `skype` to `bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype'`.

Comment: any possible reason?

Comment: Yeah, skype is not loading the video4linux library in 11.10, your not the only one as you can see from the `Possible duplicate` ticket under your question. Its just happening at the moment, nothing you have done or can do to solve it except wait ;) gl

Answer (score 0):

if you have Skype 4.2 installed (on Ubuntu 12.04 or latest, provided you've installed `ia32-libs` from Synaptic) don't open Skype from the launcher, just  open your terminal and paste: `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype`  and see how your camera will work just fine on Skype.