# My webcam won't work online

Tags: webcam

A tiny box pop up and asks me if I want to allow or decline something, and I click "accept" but nothing happens. The box keeps being there and just is there. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these answers mentioned on my previous post at: [How make my Logitech Quickcam e3500 work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63137/how-make-my-logitech-quickcam-e3500-work/63157#63157) which I reproduce here for you and that may not help you to fix this issue but will allow you to use your webcam in web based video-chat services (such as www.ubiqq.com).

> This seems to be such a common issue when attempting to use the
>   webcam, usb based, for a video conference through a flash player based
>   system, such as Fonomo, Ubiqq, or Skype, etc.
>
> I suggest you to take a look at the answers provided in these
>   questions, which may lead to help you to fix this issue.
>
> 1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/53495/flash-crashes-on-enabling-webcam/53615#53615
> 2. [Webcam not detected by Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53028/webcam-not-detected-by-flash/56324#56324)
> 3. [logitec webcam for notebooks deluxe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57398/logitec-webcam-for-notebooks-deluxe/57539#57539)
> 4. [QuickCam E 3500 working from Cheese, but not Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23253/quickcam-e-3500-working-from-cheese-but-not-skype/23298#23298)
>
> In my case I fixed that issue by using the Flashcam Project, mentioned
>   on these answers and whose instructions for a correct usage can be
>   reached right here: http://www.swift-tools.net/Flashcam/
>
> Another good trick that makes my days when attempting to use the
>   webcam through web browsers is the usage of Webcam Studio, which can
>   be reached here: http://www.ws4gl.org/. After running the Webcam
>   Studio you will have a virtual "bridge" between your physical webcam
>   and what the Flash Player is expecting to find.
>
> I hope this gives you a clue on where to begin.
>
> Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

go to 
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager08.html
and click on the website you want it to be and click always allow . refresh the other website and you're good to go :)

Comment: oh and go on the icon with the computerscreen with the eye