# Logitech C310 webcam not working well with Guvcview and Cheese

Tags: webcam, cheese

I just bought a new webcam, Logitech C310.
It doesn't work well with either Guvcview or Cheese with their default settings, under Ubuntu 12.04.
The recorded video and audio are not synchronized in both Guvcview and Cheese. The sound lags behind the video. Is the problem due to the webcam or Guvcview and Cheese?

I haven't been able to test the webcam with skype yet. Not sure if the same synchronized problem will occur.

What webcams do you recommend to work with Ubuntu 12.04? I prefer one that can work well for online job interview.

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to your edit, I can say the problem is in the webcam itself. Some webcams won't work out of the box. Including some Logitech. This errors can be fixed with lots of efforts but the fix won't be permanent so you will be struggling with the "fix" each time you wish to use the webcam. In certain cases you will be forced to reboot your computer in order to use it. That behavior is far from "easy" thus I suggest you to give a chance to a better supported webcam. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Making Logitech webcams to work in Ubuntu may be a nightmare but you may succeed with some efforts, of which I suggest you to take a look at the list of possibilities mentioned in [**this previous answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/80321/9598). The [**Swift Tools Flashcam Project**](http://www.swift-tools.net/Flashcam/) can be useful for you but it is tricky and not fully reliable. It is yet worth a try.

My suggestion for a good webcam will be a [**Microsoft VX-800**](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/lifecam-vx-800) which will work right out of the box with no problem and excellent quality.

[image]

Samples of this webcam in action for a production workflow can be seen [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKt6TP1MGtM) and in the latest videos of the official [DiarioDebateTV Channel in Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/DiarioDebateTV), of which I suggest you to see them in 480p quality. This model is what we use for a live broadcast.

I hope you can find this model, it is cheap and will require no additional drivers, patches or programs to work out of the box.

Good luck!